# Sticky navbar using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to create to nav bar that goes pops up when the users scrolls up and when they reach the end of the page. reference can be the nav bar in Nike website. I wrote the JScript for this, but that doesn't do the work.

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar');
let topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;

function fixNav() {
  if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
    document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav');
  } else {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    document.body.classList.remove('fixed-nav');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);

// show nav bar when at the end of the page
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    nav.classList.add('show-nav');
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove('show-nav');
  }
};
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list" id="navbar">
    <li>
      <a href="%">Test</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why not just use `position: sticky` ?

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has an example on this, check if it works for you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can see some problems

- Use of `querySelector` returns a static node, which means the position stays fixed all the time and you're running `fixNav` each time with the same `topOfNav` which means you'll always get the same result, instead, you either query your navbar inside the `fixNav` or use `getElementsById` which returns live node.
- Use of `paddingTop` instead of `marignTop`, you're resizing your navbar instead of moving it
- Your classes do not exist in the css as well, you need to include them if you want me to provide a solution instead of hints, but mostly likely, you didn't position your navbar bar, which means it's static and positioning properties like `top` and `bottom` won't work on it. Instead, you need to make it `relative` for this to work.

Or just use `position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0` and it should stick while scrolling